# Clearing DataTable Automatically Before Filling

Tags: mysql, .net, datatable, dataset

I just had a quick question.  I'm new to .net.  Is there a way to set the DataTable to clear itself everytime before I fill it?  I was looking at TableAdapter and saw the 'ClearBeforeFill property' and was thinking that something like that existed for the DataAdapter or DataTables specifically.

```vb
'Construct query
Dim queryAccountData$ = "SELECT * FROM " & TableName & " WHERE AccountNumber=" & AccountNumber

'Execute query and fill datatable in dataset
Using adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(queryAccountData, connection)
    adapter.Fill(DS, "Holdings")
End Using

With DS.Tables("Holdings")
     'Assign variables
     rows_lastIndex = .Rows.Count - 1
     If rows_lastIndex = -1 Then Throw New ApplicationException("Account Number Not Found In Database")
etc....
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean create a copy of a existing datatable? The question is not clear enough.

Comment: @KayNelson No, I thought I might as well reuse the same DataTable so I was wondering if there was a method or something I could use to clear it before it's filled.  I guess I was looking at the TableAdapter and saw the 'ClearBeforeFill property' and was thinking that something like that existed for the DataAdapter or DataTables specifically.

Comment: Well, when you use dt.Clear() you clear the entire datatable and the structure. To keep structure and olny clear data you can use dt.rows.clear()